# Loading Multiple Fragments with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I'd like to bring in multiple fragments from 1 webpage into a div but the only way I have been able to get it working is by using multiple .load() functions.

Is there a way to simplify the following into 1 html request?

```
$('.quickview-dialog-left').load('/productlargetest .productlargeimage img');
$('.quickview-dialog-right').append('<div class="top"><div class="title"></div><div class="price"></div><div class="delivery"></div></div><div class="bottom"><div class="shortdescription"></div><div class="options"></div><div class="buttons"><div class="buy"></div><div class="viewmore">More Details</div></div></div><div class="close">[x] close</div>');
$('.quickview-dialog-right .title').load('/productlargetest .productrighttop h1');
$('.quickview-dialog-right .price').load('/productlargetest .productprice');
$('.quickview-dialog-right .delivery').load('/productlargetest .productrighttop .stock-delivery');
$('.quickview-dialog-right .bottom .shortdescription').load('/productlargetest .shortdescription');
$('.quickview-dialog-right .bottom .options').load('/productlargetest .productoption');
$('.quickview-dialog-right .bottom .buttons .buy').load('/productlargetest .productSubmitInput');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to try.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZWsLA/1/

```
//do a 'get' here ONCE, this will get your page as an HTML string
$.get("/HEaUk/1/show/", function(data1){

    //store that HTML string in some hidden div local on the page.  The reason that I store is locally in a DIV is because jQuery seems to be able to parse it much easier.
    $("#everything").html(data1);

    //now you can just use the 'find' method to grab whatever you want from your html and append, or insert into whatever you want.
    $(".quickview-dialog-left").html(
        //use your normal jQuery selector here to 'find' the elements that you need
        $("#everything").find('#productlargeimage').text()
    );

    //here is an example with 'append', but at this point you can do whatever you want with your selectors
    $(".quickview-dialog-right").append(
        $("#everything").find('#productrighttop').text()
    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with one load but you can do it with one `ajax` call.  You can load the results of your `ajax` (or `get`/`post`) into a new document and then pull out the parts that you want.

Look at the source of jquery's load, found at: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L133

```
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
if ( typeof url !== "string" && _load ) {
return _load.apply( this, arguments );
}

// Don't do a request if no elements are being requested
if ( !this.length ) {
return this;
}

var selector, type, response,
self = this,
off = url.indexOf(" ");

if ( off >= 0 ) {
selector = url.slice( off, url.length );
url = url.slice( 0, off );
}

// If it's a function
if ( jQuery.isFunction( params ) ) {

// We assume that it's the callback
callback = params;
params = undefined;

// Otherwise, build a param string
} else if ( params && typeof params === "object" ) {
type = "POST";
}

// Request the remote document
jQuery.ajax({
url: url,

// if "type" variable is undefined, then "GET" method will be used
type: type,
dataType: "html",
data: params,
complete: function( jqXHR, status ) {
if ( callback ) {
self.each( callback, response || [ jqXHR.responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
}
}
}).done(function( responseText ) {

// Save response for use in complete callback
response = arguments;

// See if a selector was specified
self.html( selector ?

// Create a dummy div to hold the results
jQuery("<div>")

// inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
// to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
.append( responseText.replace( rscript, "" ) )

// Locate the specified elements
.find( selector ) :

// If not, just inject the full result
responseText );

});

return this;
};
```

Given this, note at the bottom where it loads (`self.html(...)`) then uses a selector to copy from the temporary `self` to the final document.  I'm not sure how proficient you are with jquery so I'm not sure if you need me to spell out all the steps or if this gets you what you need.